# How to use Stringbuilder to insert multiple Listview Item into sqldatabase?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have trouble when I'm trying to insert multiple listview items into an SQL database at once. I want to use the `StringBuilder` to achieve this. For example, I want to Append the below Item code and Item name and save in just one row in the database i.e. 001 = Bread, 002 = meat pie and etc...

Item code - 001, 002, 003, 004, 005

Item name - Bread, meat pie, fish roll, egg roll, donut

So that all the 'Item name' string data will be in store in one row in the database after l have click the Save button. Below is my code

```
foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("INSERT INTO Snack (Item code, Itemname)");
    sb.Append(" VALUES (@d1, @d2)");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), con);
        
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", i.SubItems[0].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", i.SubItems[1].Text);           

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: So...What's the issue you're having?  I don't understand what exact problem needs to be solved.

Comment: Are you saying you want to join all the items with a comma? And do you mean all of the subitems or something else?

Comment: Are you wanting to store a comma-separated list of values into a column? That's a very bad database design decision that will cause you nothing but problems forever.

Comment: For the code you show, you don't need a StringBuilder.

Comment: It's impossible for me to understand how your listview looks and I don't understand what things like "001 = Bread" mean. Do you want to save all listView1.Items in one record or do you want to group by SubItem[0] and then write all SubItem[1] with same item code to one record?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, yes i want to join all the subitem in each column to be save in the database

Comment: `string.Join(", ", i.SubItems.Select(i => i.Text))`?

Comment: @Christoph Lutjen, yes i want to save all the listview item in one record

Comment: Then you'd have to take listView1.Items, Select() what text you need and then you can use string.Join() to create one single string. If I understood this correctly...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a StringBuilder in the loop and then execute the query. It should look like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("INSERT INTO Snack (Item code, Itemname) VALUES");
foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
{
     sb.Append($" ({ i.SubItems[0].Text},{i.SubItems[1].Text}),");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
sb.Append(";");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```